# What is the right way to say: "I like this author's writing style"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I am not a native English speaker and have a difficult time putting this idea into one sentence.

I read one research paper and I really enjoy his writing style. How can I say that in one sentence?

My attempts are:

- I like the writing style of this author.
- I like this author's writing style.
- I like the writing style from this book.

I am not sure if my grammar is correct either. Please suggest me.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say 'I love your work'. It's universal and fits everywhere.

Comment: I think you've expressed it just fine with "I like this author's writing style.".  What makes you think there's anything wrong with that?

Comment: I feel that whenever I have to use 's - my sentence does not look concise. But if I use 'of' to avoid 's, then the sentence become longer. So I seek for a concise way to express this simple idea.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I like your/this author's style" is fine by itself, but if you want to be more in-depth, you could try picking out a specific part or parts of it: "I like the way this author uses imagery", for example, or "I find this author's writing style to be clear and easy to read".

Your grammar is fine, though the first one sounds a little formal. The second reads more naturally.